# Python3.8: splitting a data file into several files all of which are named by a keyword in the file

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a data file that has some key words at the beginning of each line:

ATOM    145 HH11 ARG A   9       1.714  -4.146 -13.917  1.00 60.34           H
ATOM    146 HH12 ARG A   9       2.108  -5.132 -15.287  1.00  3.13           H
ATOM    147 HH21 ARG A   9       0.626  -2.990 -17.619  1.00 10.52           H
ATOM    148 HH22 ARG A   9       1.490  -4.473 -17.392  1.00 13.53           H
TER     149      ARG A   9
MODEL        2
ATOM      1  N   ARG A   1       0.642  -0.735  -0.097  1.00  2.52           N
ATOM      2  CA  ARG A   1       1.593  -0.712  -1.202  1.00 73.00           C
ATOM      3  C   ARG A   1       0.987  -1.343  -2.452  1.00 65.25           C

I have split the original files by:

```
with open('abc.pdb', 'r') as file_in:
    with open('abc_models.pdb', 'w') as file_out:
        for line in file_in:
            if line.startswith('MODEL') or line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('TER'):
                file_out.write(line)
```

Now I would like to take this single file and split it up as follows:

MODEL 1 ----> TER (name this model 1)
MODEL 2 ----> TER (name this model 2)

Can anyone tell me how to split this file up as I described?

Comment: Side-note: `startswith` (and `endswith`) can take a `tuple` of strings to recognize, and return `True` if it starts (or ends for `endswith`) with any of them. So `if line.startswith('MODEL') or line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('TER'):` can be spelled `if line.startswith(('MODEL', 'ATOM', 'TER')):` and it's a both shorter and faster to execute than what you have.

Comment: Thanks, Shadow Ranger- I was wondering if that was possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('abc.pdb', 'r') as file_in:
    for line in file_in:    
        if line.startswith('MODEL'):
            file_out = open(f'abc_{line}.pdb', 'w')
        elif line.startswith('TER'):
            file_out.close()
        else:
            file_out.write(line)
```